# Al cargar todas las imágenes salir de la función scroll

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, imagen

Tengo una web en la que a medida que se va haciendo scroll se van añadiendo divs con imágenes (van apareciendo imágenes, vamos), por tanto, cada vez que la barra lateral llega al final de su recorrido, añade una imagen nueva al "DOM".

¿Habría alguna forma de que cuando no queden imágenes que cargar/añadir (que son 137 (número fijo)), no haga caso a la función `$(window).scroll(function()`? Es decir, que cuando el contador llegue o sobrepase el 137, salga de la función scroll o no haga caso a esta función.

He probado con break, exit, poniendo otro if... pero nada, no funciona y no se me ocurre nada más. Pongo parte del código:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 13;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()){
           if(i <= 137){
              (function(){
                 $('div.cuadricula').append(function(){
                     result += "<img ....>";
                     i = i + 1;
                     return result;
                  });
                })();
            }else{}
         }
      });           

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
```

En conclusión, mi pregunta es si hay alguna forma de que en el momento que quiera, que haga caso omiso a la funciona scroll, que la salte, hacer como si no existiera, ...

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es simplemente quitar el controlador del evento scroll utilizando el método `off` de jQuery una vez se hayan cargado todas las imágenes.

Algo así:

```js
$(function(){
  var i = 13;
  
  $(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()){
      $('div.cuadricula').append('<div class="imagen">Imagen ' + (i++) + '</div>');
      if (i > 137){
        $(window).off('scroll');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.imagen{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cuadricula">
  <div class="imagen">Imagen 1</div>
  <div class="imagen">Imagen 2</div>
  <div class="imagen">Imagen 3</div>
  <div class="imagen">Imagen 4</div>
  <div class="imagen">Imagen 5</div>
  <div class="imagen">Imagen 6</div>
  <div class="imagen">Imagen 7</div>
  <div class="imagen">Imagen 8</div>
  <div class="imagen">Imagen 9</div>
  <div class="imagen">Imagen 10</div>
  <div class="imagen">Imagen 11</div>
  <div class="imagen">Imagen 12</div>
  <div class="imagen">Imagen 13</div>
</div>
```